# When is the parent class variables available to use in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance

```
class frozen(object) :
    isFrozen = False
    print 'In base'

class layer(frozen):
    print isFrozen
```

I am trying to understand the inheritance concept in Python, the above lines are a silly example. "print" statement in the parent class is working as I try to create an object of layer class. But it's throwing an error at the "print" statement of the child class. Saying "isFrozen" is not defined.

But, if I comment out the "print" statement in child class, I can create an object of the child class and access "isFrozen" as "layerObject.isFrozen".

So, could anyone please point out my misunderstanding here?

Comment: Have you read [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables)?

Comment: I had come across that particular tutorial. But, it does not help me to understand the cause of error in the above case. "isFrozen" is defined as a class variable. But why can't I access it from child class?

Comment: @MazharulIslam because you're not accessing it on the class, you're treating it as a global. Only names already defined within the current class definition, not those of its parents, are available without qualification.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation: "The class body is executed in a new namespace".

Answer (score 0):

Class body provides a namespace and classes (unlike functions) are parsed when the module is read (import time). Your problem is that you are calling `isFrozen` of the `frozen` class without the namespace. Also to take full advantage of inheritance you need an actual class instance which is usually referred to as `self`:

```
class Frozen(object):
    isFrozen = False
    def __init__(self):
      print Frozen.isFrozen
      print "From Base"


class Layer(Frozen):

    def __init__(self):
      print self.isFrozen ##this is defined by the parent
      print "From subclass"
      self.isFrozen = True
      print self.isFrozen


In [7]: test_class = Layer()
False
From subclass
True

In [8]: test_class.isFrozen
Out[8]: True
```

And a RTFM is suggested here as well.

Comment: They're parsed way earlier - before the Python source code is compiled to Python byte code. The class bodies of classes are **executed**, however, when the `class` statement itself is executed.

Comment: Nitpicking, but whole module source is *parsed* before it even can be executed. [Function definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) are executed during module load, which for example leads to the infamous "why is my default list argument preserved between calls". A function definition does not execute the body, which I guess is what you meant.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yes that is what I meant. Good callout though.